# CSVHelper: One Row, multiple classmaps

Tags: csvhelper

I have a row that is acting as a composite of multiple classes. These classes thereafter represent a nested, aggregated object.
e.g.:

(header)product_name, product_sku, product_description, promotion_date, promotion_price

(data) xxx, 1234, "great product", 12/4/202, $3.41

I want to read the first 3 cols in the Product object then the other two into the Promotion object.
Can I do this with two maps? Can I create a view between two classes in the classMap?

Comment: Show some code, without more, I assume you can use LINQ to join and aggregate your data and then feed csvhelper an  anonymous object.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it with several maps

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("product_name,product_sku,product_description,promotion_date,promotion_price");
            writer.WriteLine("xxx,1234,great product,12/4/202,$3.41");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TransactionMap>();

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Transaction>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class TransactionMap : ClassMap<Transaction>
{
    public TransactionMap()
    {
        References<ProductMap>(m => m.Product);
        References<PromotionMap>(m => m.Promotion);
    }
}

public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Name).Name("product_name");
        Map(m => m.Sku).Name("product_sku");
        Map(m => m.Description).Name("product_description");
    }
}

public class PromotionMap : ClassMap<Promotion>
{
    public PromotionMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Date).Name("promotion_date");
        Map(m => m.Price).Name("promotion_price");
    }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Promotion Promotion { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Promotion
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

Or with one map

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("product_name,product_sku,product_description,promotion_date,promotion_price");
            writer.WriteLine("xxx,1234,great product,12/4/202,$3.41");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TransactionMap>();

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Transaction>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class TransactionMap : ClassMap<Transaction>
{
    public TransactionMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Product.Name).Name("product_name");
        Map(m => m.Product.Sku).Name("product_sku");
        Map(m => m.Product.Description).Name("product_description");
        Map(m => m.Promotion.Date).Name("promotion_date");
        Map(m => m.Promotion.Price).Name("promotion_price");
    }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Promotion Promotion { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Promotion
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```